# How to use Handwriting Recognition model as an API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have created one machine learning model using Tensorflow and Keras by using IAM dataset. How to load this model as an API to predict an image? When I was trying to integrate It shows error

```
return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "test2.py", line 136, in resize_image
    return tf.image.resize_images(image,[56,56])
    NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

I have load model using *from keras.models import load_model* and trying to predict image handwriting. `low_loss.hdf5` is model which I try to integrate.

```
def testmodel(image_path):
      global model
    # load the pre-trained Keras model
      model = load_model('low_loss.hdf5')
      model.summary()
      img = Image.open(image_path).convert("L")
      img = np.resize(image_path, (28,28,1))
      im2arr = np.array(img)
      im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1,28,28,1)
      y_pred = model.predict_classes(im2arr)
      return y_pred
```

I wish to predict image Handwritten data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were getting an error because you have not imported TensorFlow in your code or if you have imported you have not given an alias.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 1):

your error is about tf which is not loaded.

try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```